# How to click all items with a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following items on the html page:

```
$(".pv-profile-section__card-action-bar").length
3
```

How would I click all of them instead of just the first one, which is done via:

```
$(".pv-profile-section__card-action-bar").click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `each` to iterate over every item, and then you can trigger a `click` on each:

```js
$(".pv-profile-section__card-action-bar").click(function() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
});

$(".pv-profile-section__card-action-bar").each(function() {
  $(this).click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pv-profile-section__card-action-bar">foo</div>
<div class="pv-profile-section__card-action-bar">bar</div>
```